# Size, minimum and maximum values of data types in C

Tags: c, types, size, unsigned

I need to determine the size, the minimum and the maximum values of the following types in C:

- char
- unsigned char
- short
- int
- unsigned int
- unsigned long
- float

I would like if someone could help me clarify the following:

1. What is exactly meant by the word "size" in this context?

For example, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    int h = sizeof(c);
    printf("%.6d\n", h);

    int n;
    h = sizeof(n);
    printf("%.6d\n", h);
}
```

It outputs 1 for char and 4 for int. What do these numbers mean?

2. How does one determine the minimum and maximum values with some simple beginner C code?
3. What does the word "unsigned" mean in this context?

Comment: You need to read up on the C programming language.

Comment: For _unsigned_ types, the max value is `(some_unsigned_type)-1`.  For _signed_ types, use constants like `xxx_MAX`.

Comment: For minimum and maximum values that a specific type of variable can represent, look at the contents in "limits.h", which contains the constants which @chux refers to.  As to what the values "1" or "4" in your output mean, it is the number of octets a "char" and "int" variable occupies, respectively (i.e. the "sizeof" that variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What is exactly meant by the word "size" in this context?

With `h = sizeof(n);`, `sizeof` is the the number of *bytes* the object takes up in memory.  In C, a "byte" if often 8 bits, but may be more. Use `CHAR_BITS`.

> number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
> `CHAR_BIT                 8` (minimum value)
> C11 dr §5.2.4.2.1 1
>
> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of n × `CHAR_BIT` bits, where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. ...
> §6.2.6.1 4

To properly compute and print size, use type `size_t` and `"%zu"`.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

some_type n;
size_t h = sizeof(n);
printf("Byte size: %zu, Bits/byte: %d, Bit size: %zu\n", h, CHAR_BIT, h * CHAR_BIT);
// Octet is the common "outside of C" meaning of a "byte" of 8 bits/byte
printf("Octet size: %g\n", (h * CHAR_BIT)/8.0);
```

---

2. How does one determine the minimum and maximum values with some simple beginner C code?

C is type rich - there are many types. Robust code does not try to calculate the min/max of a type but uses constants defined in various include files.

To attempt to write code that calculates the min/max of a type (other than *unsigned types*) often runs into *undefined behavior* (UB) or *implementation defined behavior*. Avoid that.

```
// FP limits
#include <float.h>
// Standard integers 
#include <limits.h>
// Fixed width, minimum width, fast integers 
#include <stdint.h>
// Extended multibyte/wide characters
#include <wchar.h>
```

To print these, be sure to use a correct type and value.  For details on this, research `fprintf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

printf("char            range %d ... %u\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
printf("unsigned char   range %u ... %u\n", 0, UCHAR_MAX);
printf("short           range %d ... %d\n", SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
printf("int             range %d ... %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
printf("unsigned int    range %u ... %u\n", 0, UINT_MAX);
printf("unsigned long   range %lu ... %lu\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
printf("float           finite range %.*g ... %.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, -FLT_MAX,
   FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, FLT_MAX);
```

Example output - Yours may differ

```
char            range -128 ... 127
unsigned char   range 0 ... 255
short           range -32768 ... 32767
int             range -2147483648 ... 2147483647
unsigned int    range 0 ... 4294967295
unsigned long   range 0 ... 18446744073709551615
float           finite range -3.40282347e+38 ... 3.40282347e+38
```

Many compilers support + or +/- *infinity* with floating point types.  With such, the maximum `float` is then `INFINITY`.  Research `HUGE_VALF` for additional ideas of `float` max.

---

3. What does the word "unsigned" mean in this context?

The *integer* type lacks a sign bit.  It minimum value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

1. The word size used in sizeof means how many bytes the type occupies in memory. In a typical architecture an integer is often 4 bytes (32 bit) while a char is defined to be 1 byte (8 bit).
2. To get the minimum value and the maximum value you can use the library limits.h as explained [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm). For example, if you want to know the maximum value an integer can store, you can simply output the constant `INT_MAX`
3. The word "unsigned" means that the bytes will be used to store only natural numbers, so without "sign". For example, `unsigned int` is used for numbers from 0 to 4,294,967,295 (4 byte int) while `int` stores from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (again 4 byte int)
4. The number of bits per byte can vary between architectures, in addition to the number of bytes per datatype (except char) varying.